# How can I convert json map to List String?

Tags: list, dart, flutter

I need to get country name and country code into List as "Andorra (AD)". I can load json to a map but I cannot convert to List. How can I convert json map to List String?

"country": [
        {
            "countryCode": "AD",
            "countryName": "Andorra",
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "isoNumeric": "020"
        },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.map()` function

```
var countryList = country.map((c) => '${c["countryName"]} (${c["countryCode"]})').toList()
```